# How should I design a horseradish bed?

Tags: root-vegetables, water, back-to-eden

I'm building a horseradish bed with the Back to Eden method about 2 feet above the water line (floods every 5-10 years) along a creek. Will this be enough room to grow good sized horseradish roots?

Comment: Horse radish is wonderful.  It takes a bit of time at the beginning to get decent roots to use but make no mistake.  Horse radish can be very invasive.  I've got my first horse radish to grow in this garden.  I will have to insert root guards and keep it from seeding so it doesn't take over.  I need to do this with raspberries!  Are you thinking that a 5 to 10 year flood will help water your horse radish?  When you get a flood, bits and pieces of horse radish will be washed down stream to invade other properties.  What again does Back to Eden Method mean to you?

Comment: i'll be 10 feet back, and doing lasagna down to the top water table to make the roots easier to pull up. I'm worried about root rot in the 5-10 year flood zone as I'll be filling the horseradish bed with wood chips, and manure to get incredibly rich soil. Back to Eden makes it easier to  pull roots up as they're established., and promotes mycelium to tell plants to grow bigger faster, with more medicinal abilities.

Comment: Lasagna gardening was never meant for gardening it was designed for compost beds...composting, not soil.  How can I get you to look at wood chips as a nitrogen sponge?  Otherwise, what the heck good are they?  Until they are decomposed the wood chips are worthless.  Mycelium does not tell plants to grow better...nor have better medicinal qualities.  Argghh.  Give me another site that TRIES to explain this...

Comment: What is it that you expect using wood chips and 'back to Eden'?  I think fungus is critical but is always THERE in all soils.  Do not need wood chips to promote fungus that is for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes it will be plenty of room as horseradish roots are only going to get about 1 ft in length. However, when its floods they may very well experience root rot and die.

Comment: pull when the flood happens